# Initializing venvs in python3.4

Tags: python-3.x, python-venv

The old virtualenv script had a file `activate_this.py` that could be executed with `execfile` to prepare an interpreter.  The new `venv` module in Python 3.4's standard library doesn't ship with it.  How can I set up a Python interpreter to use a venv programmatically like you could with `activate_this.py`?

edit: Bonus question, is there an obvious reason why it's missing?  Did something change in Python?

Answer (score 0):

The `activite_this.py` script is part of the [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) package.

The latest versions of [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and [virtualenvwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper/) are compatible with Python 3.x `venv`.